# Next JS sending to two URL's in API call

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Just like the title says. When I am attempting to make my call using axios, I get the following address in my console http://localhost:3000/'http:/localhost:8000/api/register

I have the base url in an .env.local variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_API=http://localhost:8000/api`. I am using Next JS 13. I have added the code block below. I am thinking it has something to do with the component being in the 'app' directory, but could we off base.

```
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import axios from 'axios';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

const Register = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(name, email, password);

    // Make API request
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/register`,
        {
          name,
          email,
          password
        }
      );
      setLoading(false);
      log('register => ', data);
      toast.success('Register Success!');
      router.push('/');
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      toast.error(error.response.data.error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100 '>
        <div className='row border border-light border-1 border-secondary rounded shadow pb-5 pt-5'>
          <h2 className='mb-5 text-center'>Register</h2>
          <form action='' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type='text'
              value={name}
              onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
              placeholder='Enter your name'
              className='form-control mb-3'
            />
            <input
              type='email'
              value={email}
              onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              placeholder='Enter your email'
              className='form-control mb-3'
            />
            <input
              type='password'
              value={password}
              onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              placeholder='Enter your email'
              className='form-control mb-3'
            />
            <div className='d-grid'>
              <button
                className='btn btn-primary text-align-center'
                disabled={loading || !name || !email || !password}
              >
                {loading ? (
                  <div className='spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-light'>
                    <span className='visually-hidden'></span>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  'Submit'
                )}
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the responses. I figured it out. Extracting the logic out of the next.js "app" folder and putting it in a component fixed the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate some? I am facing a similar kind of issue when the server is being called frequently which is causing out of memory crashes